# Count specific edges for Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

Hello im currently working on a Dijkstras algoritm. I would like to count the amout of specific edges that are chosen in order to change the cost of the next edge etc. I have a problem adding how many times a specific edge has been choosen. I link parts of my code.

```html
Edge dirC = new Edge("d" + nodes.get(i * ds.columns + j), nodes.get(i * ds.columns + j), nodes.get((i + 1) * ds.columns + j), downcost1);
edges.add(dirC);
```

In this part a specific edge "dirC" is added. I would like to add one "dicCcount" and then get the value of the counter back in order to use it in a if statement after this part has been run. The Edge class looks like this.

```html
package autonavigate;

public class Edge  {
  private final String id; 
  private final Vertex source;
  private final Vertex destination;
  private final double weight; 
  
  public Edge(String id, Vertex source, Vertex destination, double weight) {
    this.id = id;
    this.source = source;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.weight = weight;
  }
  
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }
  
  public Vertex getDestination() {
    return destination;
  }

  public Vertex getSource() {
    return source;
  }
  public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
  }
  
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return source + " " + destination;
  }
 }
```

I've tried to solve this for hours but i cant figure out how to do it. Its not a homework its a program i've done for a remote control car :).

Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem, you might consider one of the following:

1. a dictionary data structure (defined outside of the Edge data type) to keep track of selected edges, with counters (as values) that would be incremented each time the edge is selected; this would be updated as you trace through your graph (it should be disposed of at the end of the tracing algorithm)
2. an extension to your Edge data type that implements the behavior of being "selected" and internally keeping track of how many times it has been visited during a tracing run (with option to reset its internal counter)